# Spring boot microservice accessing file on spring config server both of which are deployed on Docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a java spring based microservices env deployed on docker containers using docker compose.
The microservice lets call A reads properties and configs from a spring configuration server. The set up works successfully on local but in docker its throwing a FileNotFound error.

I am reading the file using **@PropertySource**

**Microservice A:**

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "file:../configurations/src/main/resources/properties/common/event-mapping.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api")
public class EventMapping {...}
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    configurationsService:
        image: "configurations-service"
        hostname: configurationsService
        ports:
          - "9080:9080"
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS:
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=native,dev"  
        healthcheck:
              test: "curl --fail --silent configurationsService:9080/actuator/health | grep UP || exit 1"
              interval: 20s
              timeout: 5s
              retries: 5
              start_period: 40s
          
    microserviceA:
        image: "microservice-A"
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
              configurationsService:
                condition: service_healthy
                restart: true
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS:
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

**Logs**

```
microserviceA-1            | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../configurations/src/main/resources/properties/common/event-mapping.yml (No such file or directory)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.handleProcessError(YamlProcessor.java:222)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:214)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:166)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.java:135)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject(YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.java:115)
microserviceA-1            |     at com.openreach.inams.createalarm.config.YamlPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(YamlPropertySourceFactory.java:21)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceProcessor.processPropertySource(PropertySourceProcessor.java:87)
microserviceA-1            |     at org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySourceRegistry.processPropertySource(PropertySourceRegistry.java:77)
```

Comment: Your `@PropertySource` is wrong use `classpath:/properties/common/event-mapping.yml` and make sure that your `configuration.jar` is on your classpath. Or set the `ignoreResourceNotFound` property to `true`, so that if just ignores the warning and skips reading the file (as I assume you only want that to be read during dev/test and not during regular runs).

Comment: I figured this out, so instead of accessing the file using `file:<..pathToFIle>` I accessed using the url of the config server followed by the location of file ib the classpath of the config server. `http://configurationsService:51236/native/classpath:properties/common/event-mapping.yml`. `native` is the active spring profile name.

Answer (score -1):

Hy,

You may be able to solve your problem with using shared volumes between your containers.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/